# is the Canon 430 ex speedlite compatible with the Nikon D90?

Tags: nikon-d90, compatibility, canon-ex430ii

Can I use a Canon 430 ex speedlite with a Nikon d90 DSLR? I want to buy a Nikon D90 and use the existing Canon 430 ex.  Would it work in TTL or manual mode?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will fire, but it is unlikely that TTL metering will work properly.

Given that TTL is one of the most important functions of an on-camera flash (speedlight), then I would not advise going with a canon/Nikon mix.